# How to declare template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Suppose I have two classes `Foo1<T>` and `Foo2<T>`.

I then want to create a function `bar` that takes a reference to a `std::vector<Foo1<T>>` or to a `std::vector<Foo2<T>>` but *always* returns a `std::vector<Foo1<T>>`:

`template<class T, class Y> std::vector<Foo1<T>> bar(std::vector<Y<T>>&)`

Sadly but the compiler doesn't like the `<Y<T>>` bit. One way round this is to provide two overloads but is there a way I can arrange the above so it's correct?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need [template template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter):

```
template<class T, template <typename> class Y> 
std::vector<Foo1<T>> bar(std::vector<Y<T>>&) {}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are an angel!

Comment: Starting with C++14 `Y` also can be declared with `typename` instead of only `class`.  The `T` parameter always could be declared thus.  just a little syntactic consistency added to the language.

Comment: @emsr I like to use `class` exclusively inside `template` brackets, just so to make searching for `typename T::type` constructs easier.